# Display canvas in menubar electron OSX

Tags: javascript, macos, canvas, electron

I have a simple electron app which updates the trayMenu every X seconds with some text data, but now, I want to colorize the text (green/red) in the menubar.

I found a solution to do it with a canvas converted into a base64 image, but the text stays pixelized (non-retina canvas).

Do you know how I can do that?

Canvas image (I can set different color with this way but the text is not smooth)
[image: Canvas image]

Text only (Only white but the text is smooth): 
[image: text only]

Thanks by advance

Regards

Comment: Could you be more specific about your question, maybe link the base64 image example

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I updated the documentation with 2 screenshots of the menubar rendering